# : CSV file formation not working in excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to make my code use the keys from my 'data' directory, in this case 'name' and 'language', as headers in a csv file and the values as rows.

[This is what the excel file should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKpdQ.png)

[This is how it currently looks, not formated in the way I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d81Ei.png)

This is my current code:

```
import csv


data = {
    'name': ['Dave', 'Dennis', 'Peter', 'Jess'],
    'language': ['Python', 'C', 'Java', 'Python']
}

with open('mycvsfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, data.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(data)
```

I've tried many different solutios but the formating is still off.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('name.csv', index=False)
```